# In Userform how to link the value of a textbox dynamically to that of another thing like Spinbutton or checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

I am curious how to make the value of a text box dynamically change when you select a different option button or toggle with a spin button. What I have tried so far is
    Userform1.textbox1.value = spinbutton1

Is there a better way to do this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are on the right track, but it would be:

```
 Userform1.textbox1.value = spinbutton1.value
```

And, you'd want to have that code inside of the spinbutton1's change event handler.

Comment: Beautiful! thank you. If I may ask a follow up question, Where would you place the code if you wanted a label's text to dynamically change?

Comment: When you want code to run, the first thing to do is ask yourself "When do I want this code to run?"  The answer to that question will tell you where the code goes. If the label needs it's text to change dynamically, you need to know when that change has to happen. if, for example, it needs to happen when you click a button, then you need to create a click event handler for that button and put the code in there. Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer. Thanks!